# Calling the Refresh() method which is in the main activity from another activity

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app using java, but I have the problem below.
I have the main activity where there is a button "add" and a listview. When I click the add button, it will open another activity where I can add items to  the listview. After adding this item, when I click the back button from the second activity, I want that the Refresh() method from the main activity to be executed to add this item directly to the listview in the main activity. I can't find a way to solve it. I tried to make this method as static but lot of errors appear, and the all the app is stopped. Also I tried to create new instance of the main activity in the onBackPressed() method of the second activity, but the app has also stopped. Anyone can help me to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: try adding the refresh() at the end of the onCreate method in the main activity, can you provide some code to look at

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result then add a call to your `refresh` method in your `MainActivity` after you get a result back indicating that the second activity is done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following working example shows how you can accomplish what you want :-

**MainActivity** (the initial activity) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int ACTIVITY1_REQUEST_CODE = 999;
    public static final String EXTRA_MYARRAY = "extra_myarray";

    private Button next;
    private ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> myarray = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        next = this.findViewById(R.id.next);
        listView = this.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Prepare the Button's onClickListener to start the other activity
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),Activity2.class);
                // prepare to pass the data to the other activity
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_MYARRAY,myarray);
                // Start the other activity
                startActivityForResult(i,ACTIVITY1_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        // Prepare the data
        myarray.add("a");
        myarray.add("b");
        myarray.add("c");
        // Output data to the log (to show what happens)
        refresh(myarray,"INITIAL", false);
    }

    // Prepare to receive and handle the modified data when returning from other activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ACTIVITY1_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            myarray.clear();
            for(String s: data.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_MYARRAY)) {
                myarray.add(s);
            }
            refresh(data.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_MYARRAY),"RESUMED",true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Refresh
     * @param modifiedData  The modified data to be applied (see modify) as an ArrayList<String>
     * @param tagExtra      String used to indicate where the refresh was called from
     * @param modify        flag to indicate whether or not to rebuild the data
     *                      if coming from the this activity then clear and add would
     *                      empty the array and add nothing
     */
    private void refresh(ArrayList<String> modifiedData, String tagExtra, boolean modify) {
        if (modify) myarray.clear();
        for(String s: modifiedData) {
            if (modify) myarray.add(s);
            Log.d("MA_" + tagExtra,"Value is " + s);
        }
        refreshListView();
    }

    private void refreshListView() {
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myarray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity2** the invoked/2nd activity (which modifies the list and returns that modified list to the parent when the button is clicked) :-

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button finish;
    private ArrayList<String> myarray = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        finish = this.findViewById(R.id.finish);

        // Prepare the Button's onCLickListener
        finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                // Prepare to return the data
                i.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MYARRAY,myarray);
                // Indicate that all is OK
                setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
                // Finish this activity and thus pass control back to the parent activity
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Modify the data
        myarray = this.getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MYARRAY);
        myarray.add("d");

    }
}
```

- Comments should explain the code
- Note this method does use the deprecated (`startActivityForResult`) so you may wish to consider looking at *[Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java)*

**Result**

When run the App displays :-

[image]

Clicking the NEXT button takes you to the 2nd Activity :-

[image]

Clicking the FINISH button (the activity adds a new element) returns to the MainActivity which is now :-

[image]

i.e. the new element is displayed accordingly in the ListView